# *file f_flags setup in linux device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

i'm write a linux device module, and i need an ioctl function that enable the O_NONBLOCK flags so in my ioctl function i do:

```
case IOCTL_SET_NOBLOCK:

            printk(KERN_DEBUG "case IOCTL_SET_NOBLOCK");
            filep->f_flags |= O_NONBLOCK;

            if(filep->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK)
            {
                printk(KERN_DEBUG "IOCTL IS O_NONBLOCK");
            }

            mutex_unlock(&dev->ms_mutex);
            break;
```

In the case the if is true..but when i try to do a read the f_flags is still not set up correctly..
where am I wrong ?

Comment: `printk()` may do not output (immediately) without newline symbol. Try to add `\n` to the end of the string: "IOCTL IS O_NONBLOCK\n".

Comment: maybe i don't understand well but for read i mean a fops read : static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep, char *user_buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset)

Comment: Then provide your `.read` method and your user-space program which accesses the file. Correct access scenario looks like: `fd = open(...); ioctl(fd, IOCTL_SET_NONBLOCK); read(fd, ...); `.

Comment: ok with a .read it seems work, but for example i try with cat command and dont't work i dont understand why..

Comment: You set the flag for **file descriptor**, opened manually with `open()`. `cat` opens the file *by itself*, so it cannot see the flag set by you.

Comment: cat will simply not call this ioctl. Have a look at cat source https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/cat.c

Comment: ok I thought it was possible set the flag and in a second moment read...thank you guys!